# Impossible response of ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm developing a webchat website using AJAX, PHP and MySQL.

But I encounter a problem, there is a function which checks whether the person you are chatting with is still on chat (online) or he/she has dropped the chat. 
The function looks like this:

```
//some variables here
var somedata="....";
var userleftchatmsg="he/she left you,you are alone now.";

function checkifuseronline(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "check.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data:somedata
    }).done(function(r) {
        if (r.o1==2) {   
            $("#chattable").prepend(userleftchatmsg);
        } else { 
            checkifuseronline();
        }
    }); 
}
```

The thing is that "he/she left.." message appears twice sometimes, especially when a user chats with multiple partners at the same time.
Isn't that supposed to be impossible or am I wrong?

Comment: What is `r`? Maybe that is not updated fast enough?

Comment: You are prepending the message to the `#chattable` element so I don't see why it can't be displayed twice. If you call `checkifuseronline` twice and get `r.o1 == 2` twice you will see the message twice.

Comment: Maybe if you use a setTimeout function to call checkifuseronline again like `setTimeout('checkifuseronline()', 1000);`

Comment: When are you calling checkifuseronline()

Comment: @ Michal Trojanowski  mr.michal look at what triggers checkifuseronline() function for the second time and makes a loop of it.it s r.o1  if r.o1 fetchs 2 once,userleftchatmsg gets prepended and the function(checkifuseronline) doesn't get called no more

Comment: @ putvande r is variable in which ajax result is put

Comment: @JorgeCampos i prefer my style to setTimeout coz it gets stuck and doesnt work in case of overcrowding

Comment: and thanks to everyone for being cornerned i appreciate it

Comment: This function will bombard your server with http calls every second until the user leaves?

Answer (score 0):

You might not like this answer, but check out XMPP.  It's designed to solve this problem, and all the others you haven't run into yet.  http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/

Alternatively, a more direct route would be to use a NodeJS server to do this:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socket-io-and-expressjs/

The sucky answer is PHP can't do what you're trying to do.  It's a great language I use all the time, but you can't get there from here.

Good luck!